# Check for directory pattern Python

Tags: python

I have directories that are created by an application that have a basic structure.

```
G009832
   - SearchData
         _SearchDb_
         _SearchDb_.dbsync
   - WaveformCache
         file1.wcf
         file2.wcf
   ProjectNameFile.apf
   ProjectNameSettings.xml
   ProjectNameSettingsBinary.abf
```

This folder and file structure is pretty constant, the only variable is the root folder name, which is a machine name, and the amount of *.wcf waveform cache files present in the WaveformCache folder.

I want to check that users have not added any extra content to any of these folders or to any subfolder before I delete them.

At the moment I'm checking the contents of each folder with os.walk.

```
illegal = []
if IsMachineFormatted(folder): # Function that checks folder is machine folder.
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
        for f in files:
            if f == '_SearchDb_':
                pass
            elif f == '_SearchDb_.dbsync':
                pass
            elif f.endswith('.wcf'):
                pass
            elif f.endswith('.apf'):
                pass
            elif f.endswith('.xml'):
                pass
            elif f.endswith('.abf'):
                pass
            else:
                illegal.append(f)
else:
    pass
```

This is ok and returns a list of illegal files, but it isn't very elegant and it doesn't check for extra directories etc. It will also allow any number of .xml or any other allowed types of files through.

I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do this, before I start to improve on this code.

I am not aware of comparison operators for directories with python, and I would be happy enough to return something like a list of dictionaries that contains the structure of any extra files and folders that have been added to the default directory pattern. Eg.

```
difference = [{'FolderName':['Naughty.txt','illegal.etc'],{'Disobedience':['Here.txt','AndHere.txt']}]
```

Comment: I would start by reading the directory structure (or a representation of it) into a data structure. Create a similar data structure for your valid directory structure, then your problem boils down to a very simple function that compares nodes from two different trees and recurses on the children.

Comment: I could do that, but it seems pretty verbose. I was thinking more along the lines of a one liner - for root, dir, file in os.walk(path): if dir or file not in pattern: return error - but I have a variable amount of files in some dirs.

Comment: I don't think it would be much more verbose than the existing solutions, and much more flexible. Another idea could be to generate a multiline string version of the directory structure, and the valid structure, and then use difflib to generate a diff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just rewrote your code a little. It can be more elegant with `any` but it less effective (because it requires checking all ends).
I'm not sure that I got correctly your question about `error` because you gave it in the wrong syntax.

Also, I recommend you to break this code to functions to avoid 5 steps nesting:

```
from collections import defaultdict

ALLOWED_NAMES = ['_SearchDb_', '_SearchDb_.dbsync']
ALLOWED_ENDS = ['.wcf', '.apf', '.xml', '.abf']

def ends_with_any(word, ends):
    for end in ends:
        if word.endswith(end):
            return True
    return False

def is_legal_name(filename, allowed_names, allowed_ends):
    return filename in allowed_names or ends_with_any(f, allowed_ends)

illegal = defaultdict(list)
if IsMachineFormatted(folder): # Function that checks folder is machine folder.
    for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
        for f in files:
            if not is_legal_name(f, ALLOWED_NAMES, ALLOWED_ENDS):
                illegal[dirpath].append(f)
```

Comment: Thanks Valentin. I changed function to def - and f is not passed to is_legal_name - it's 'filename', but it works and is better than what I was doing.

Comment: Oh, sorry -- too much JS recently :-) Edited.

Comment: I changed 'errors' to 'difference' to make the question read better. I was thinking of the differences between valid and invalid structures as errors.